# Can the base voltage (say 5V) be lower than the collector voltage (say 12V)?

Tags: transistors

I am new to electronics so sorry if this question sounds stupid. I want to control a 2N222 transistor (the normal gain kinda way) and wanted to ask if the base voltage can be lower than the collector voltage. Will the transistor function normally?
Sorry for my poor English. I am not a native speaker.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE EE! A 2N222 is probably a typo, the real transistor is called 2N2222. Instead of asking "can I do..." it is much easier to **do what others do** so browse the internet and see how others use a 2N2222 (or really any NPN transistor) to learn how it must be used. So stop worrying about voltages being lower than other voltages or not, it will only confuse you. But anyway, Yes, the base voltage can be lower than the collector voltage. This is typically the case when the transistor is **off** or when used as a signal amplifier.

Comment: Thank you, got it!! :D

Comment: @RahulMaurya The 2N2222 is an NPN BJT. If the base voltage is (conventionally) above the collector, the BJT is (to some degree) saturated. This means it is no longer being used in "the normal gain kinda way." So the base voltage is **supposed** to be lower than the collector in normal voltage gain applications -- hopefully, all the time it operates.